# Получение bitmap c кнопки

Tags: android, java, bitmap

Добрый день. Я пишу небольшую игру, суть которой находить отличия на двух картинках. Картинки я помещаю на два Button. Я хочу отлавливать координаты нажатия на кнопку и проверять небольшую область изображения на совпадение со вторым. Для этого, как я полагаю, мне нужно получить Bitmap этого изображения, можно ли получить его напрямую с кнопки?

Comment: не очень по теме, но зачем вешать изображения на кнопки, когда у ImageView отлично выставляется OnClick?

Comment: не нужно брать картинку с кнопки. Вы же ее где то выставляете? вот там и берите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже писали в комментариях, лучше так не делать.
Но если все таки хочется, то можно поступить следующим образом:

```
btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
btn.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = btn.getDrawingCache();
```